# validation form with regex while using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, bootstrap-4

i'm trying to validate my bootstrap form with regex in javascript. I've started the javascript but don't know the right way to continue the validation with my regular expression. I'm trying to validate every input in my form before submitting it.

If anyone could help me with my issue it would be appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.
**In javascript no Jquery please**

John Simmons

HTML (This is my html bootstrap form)

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validerForm(this)">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="text-center header">Contact</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <input id="lastName" name="LN" type="text" placeholder="Nom" autofocus class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <input id="firstName" name="FN" type="text" placeholder="Prenom" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Courriel" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Téléphone" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="Message" placeholder="Entrez votre message. Nous allons vous répondre le plus tôt que possible." rows="7"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
                            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="reset" onclick="clearForm()" value="Clear">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript (this is my javascript with my regexs, I was thinking about doing a function that would verify every value entered with the regex)

```
var nameregex = /(^[A-Z][a-z]{1,24})+$/;
var emailregex= /^([A-Za-z])([A-Za-z0-9])+\@([a-z0-9\-]{2,})\.([a-z]{2,4})$/;


function validerForm(form) {
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('lastName').focus();
    }

    var valName = Formulaire.name.value;
    var valFirst = Formulaire.firstname.value;
    var valEmail = Formulaire.email.value;

    var nameValide = validationName(valName);
    var firstValide = validationFirstName(valFirst);
    var emailValide - validationEmail(valEmail);


}

function validationName(valName){
    if(nameregex.test(valName) == true){

    }else{

    }
}

function clearForm() {
    document.getElementById("form").reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use string.match()

```
i.e.: if (valEmail.match(emailregex)) { do stuff!; }
```

Comment: how can I add message error under the input thats invalide ?

Comment: Simply use negation with the NOT(!), so with the same above example : 
`if (!valEmail.match(emailregex)) { handle it here; }`